# The correct form of - listagg with case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case, listagg

I get error: `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`, but i can't find the wrong stuff.

```
(select listagg(sp.name
||' : '||
(case when count(distinct sp.name) < 1 then NULL else szf.piece END) as cou_1, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sp.name,cou_1)
from sk_positions sp, sk_stock_f SZF, sk_stock SZ 
where SZF.CODE_ID =SK.ID AND SP.RID = SZF.RID_U AND SZF.ID_SZ = SZ.ID
and sp.sk_u = (%sk%) and SZF.piece != 0)
```

I think, i have problem in  `listagg - case`.

Comment: Count the ('s and the )'s. Same number?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What's `sk`, there's no a table aliased as `sk`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan it's the current table (items SK), where i am..  it's an internal query in an entrp. program (something like SAP...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
szf.piece END) as cou_1
               ^
```

You cannot alias a sub expression but only the complete expression for the column.In `Listagg`, it should come after the `within group ()` is complete.

something like this

```
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sp.name,cou_1) as cou_1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed in Oracle.You are missing single quotes for wildcard search criteria.

```
sp.sk_u = (%sk%)
```

Correct syntax is below ( only `LIKE` works with such criteria search not `=` )

```
sp.sk_u LIKE ('%sk%')
```

Complete query should be as below

```
(select listagg(sp.name ||' : '||(case when count(distinct sp.name) < 1 
                                       then NULL 
                                       else szf.piece 
                                       END) as cou_1, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sp.name,cou_1)
from sk_positions sp, sk_stock_f SZF, sk_stock SZ 
where SZF.CODE_ID =SK.ID
      AND SP.RID = SZF.RID_U 
      AND SZF.ID_SZ = SZ.ID
      and sp.sk_u LIKE ('%sk%') 
      and SZF.piece != 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you delete it from `where` clause (the `sp.sk_u = (%sk%)`) you get the same error..

Comment: I have added the complete solution in answer edit. Check it again

Comment: Check it please, if you don't believe me [compiled](https://rextester.com/USPI60844)

Comment: Share the desired output that needs to be generated